# Enable show keyboard-shortcuts in Toolbar?

Tags: scripting, interface, workflow, customization, tools

Is there a way to preview the keyboard shortcuts of a common command in the standard toolbar much like this?

I've been told I should use the F3/spacebar search options but retrieval adds time to learning that quickly adds up exponentially and I would much rather see this information where I can easily and passively recall it until it becomes part of my own natural automaticity.

[image]

I mainly ask because I'm coming as a sculptor from other tools and I'm having to not only learn new shortcuts and memorize them but unlearn old ones and any step that makes this as painless as possible is an obvious no-brainer.

[image]

Again, being able to see this information to the right of all toolbars (even if they take up a little bit more space) is incredibly valuable not only to me but anyone who is learning this software who is coming from other tools or for new learners.

Are there ways of achieving or performing this? Whether through plugin, hidden option, editing a file somewhere -- I don't care, I just desperately want this functionality.

I am jumping ship from other tools and this is one of the big walls I've hit, even though I'm trying my very best with a cheat-sheet it makes developing real speed and automaticity genuinely difficult.

[image]

Thank-you for your time.